# split a splitted string

Tags: c#, string, rgb

I wanted to split a splitted string in C#.
Basically, I want to save an image in a form of numbers, here are the code to save it to a number in C# using GetPixel

```
TextWriter textWriter = new StreamWriter(fileName);
for (int x = 0; x < bmp.Width; x++)
{
   for (int y = 0; y < bmp.Height; y++)
   {
     Color pixel = bmp.GetPixel(x, y);
     textWriter.Write(pixel.R + "," + pixel.G + "," + pixel.B + " ");
   }
}
```

and here is a possible result: 252,255,192 252,255,192 252,255,192. 
The pixel is separated by a space, and the rgb is separated by a comma.

the problem is when i tried to convert this again into an image, here is my current code to get the rgb of a pixel.

```
TextReader textReader = new StreamReader(fileName);
string allLine = textReader.ReadLine();
string[] splitPixel = allLine.Split(' ');
string[] splitRGB = null;

for (int i=0; i<splitPixel.Length; i++) {
  splitRGB[i] = splitPixel[i].Split(',');
}
```

and here is the code to set the pixel color

```
 for (int x = 0; x < bmp.Width; x++)
 {
    for (int y = 0; y < bmp.Height; y++)
    {
       byte tempR, tempG, tempB = 0;
       tempR = Convert.ToByte(splitRGB[x]);
       tempG = Convert.ToByte(splitRGB[x+1]);
       tempB = Convert.ToByte(splitRGB[x+2]);
       Color pixel = Color.FromArgb(tempR,tempG,tempB);
       bmp.SetPixel(x, y, pixel);
    }
 }
```

Right now it's only telling me this error "Cannot implicitly convert type 'string[]' to 'string'" for the
    `splitRGB[i] = splitPixel[i].Split(',')`

Comment: Should it be splitPixel[i].Split(',') ?

Comment: @Richard, yes sorry, i forgot to add it.

Comment: `splitPixel[i].Split(',')` returns an `string[]`, and you try to set `splitRGB[i]` to `splitPixel[i].Split(',')`, but `splitRGB` is a `string[]` itself, not an `string[][]`.

Comment: From what I can see you are assigning a string[] which is created from Split(',') into splitRGB[i] which is a string. So yeah the error makes sense. Looks like you need a multidimensional array, or something like List<string[]> to store the split results.

Comment: Don't forget to close the streams!

Comment: You need to either encode the pixel location to the file, or start a new line in your text file at the end of each row of pixels.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
string[] splitPixel = allLine.Split(' ');
string[] splitRGB = new string[splitPixel.Length * 3];

for (int i=0; i<splitRGB.Length; i+=3) {
  string[] splitted = splitPixel[i].Split(',');
  splitRGB[i] = splitted[0];
  splitRGB[i + 1] = splitted[1];
  splitRGB[i + 2] = splitted[2];
}
```

EDIT: Here is a better version:

You should save the width and height of your image in the file (ie: 2x2 images have the same file format as 4*1 images), here I suggest that you save them in the first line as `width height`

```
using (TextReader textReader = new StreamReader(fileName)){
    string sizeLine = textReader.ReadLine();
    if (sizeLine == null) 
        throw new /*UnexpectedData*/Exception("invalid file!");
    string[] widthHeightStr = sizeLine.Split(' ');
    if (widthHeightStr.Length != 2) 
        throw new /*UnexpectedData*/Exception("invalid file!");
    int width = int.Parse(widthHeightStr[0]);
    int height = int.Parse(widthHeightStr[1]);
    string pixelsLine = textReader.ReadLine();
    if (onlyLine == null) 
        throw new /*UnexpectedData*/Exception("invalid file!");
    string[] splitPixel = pixelsLine.Split(' ');
    var bmp = new Bitmap(width, height);
    for (int i=0; i<splitPixel.Length; i++) {
        string[] splitted = splitPixel[i].Split(',');
        if (splitted.Length != 3) 
            throw new /*UnexpectedData*/Exception("invalid file!");
        int tempR = int.Parse(splitted[0]);
        int tempG = int.Parse(splitted[1]);
        int tempB = int.Parse(splitted[2]);
        Color pixel = Color.FromArgb(tempR,tempG,tempB);
        bmp.SetPixel(i / width, i % width, pixel);
    }   
}
```

EDIT:

```
using (TextWriter textWriter = new StreamWriter(fileName){
    textWriter.WriteLine(bmp.Width + " " + bmp.Height);
    for (int x = 0; x < bmp.Width; x++)
    {
        for (int y = 0; y < bmp.Height; y++)
        {
            Color pixel = bmp.GetPixel(x, y);
            textWriter.Write(pixel.R + "," + pixel.G + "," + pixel.B + " ");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you for your answer, but how to relate this setPixel to every pixel in my pictureBox? Since when i tried to compile it. it will gave an error that tell me x and y isn't exist in this current context.

Comment: @norman-e You need to encode that info into your file somehow.

Answer (score 1):

the error is simply explained you are trying to put an array (since split returns an array) in a string since splitRGB[i] is a string where as `splitRGB[] = splitPixel[i].Split(',');` or `splitRGB[i][] = splitPixel[i].Split(',');` <- where `splitRGB[][] = new splitRGB[10][3]` would work

so your code:

```
for (int i=0; i<splitPixel.Length; i++) 
{
   splitRGB[i] = splitPixel[i].Split(',');
}
```

if you want to put an array in a array you need multi-dimensional arrays like so:

```
string[][] splitRGB = new string[splitPixel.Length][3];
```

and the for loop to get your RGB values in 
    for (int i=0; i

```
for (int x = 0; x < bmp.Width; x++)
 {
    for (int y = 0; y < bmp.Height; y++)
    {
       byte tempR, tempG, tempB = 0;
       tempR = Convert.ToByte(splitRGB[x][0]);
       tempG = Convert.ToByte(splitRGB[x][1]);
       tempB = Convert.ToByte(splitRGB[x][2]);
       Color pixel = Color.FromArgb(tempR,tempG,tempB);
       bmp.SetPixel(x, y, pixel);
    }
 }
```

the changes are very subtle and i've got the feeling i have made a mistake my self (i never use multi dimensional arrays i create arrays of structs or classes as much as i can)

Answer (score 0):

Since i dont know what you do with the bitmap,i present you with another way to get the bitmap data to file and back in one go(you can split this to acomodate your needs).
I replace setPixel and GetPixel because they are too slow of a way to access the data,this will provide much faster outcome:

```
//assume you have a class member variable of type bitmap called sourceBitmap.

BitmapData sourceData = sourceBitmap.LockBits(new Rectangle(0, 0,
                                    sourceBitmap.Width, sourceBitmap.Height),
                                    ImageLockMode.ReadOnly, PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb);

byte[] pixelBuffer = new byte[sourceData.Stride * sourceData.Height];

Marshal.Copy(sourceData.Scan0, pixelBuffer, 0, pixelBuffer.Length);

sourceBitmap.UnlockBits(sourceData);

File.WriteAllBytes(@"C:\..\..\test.txt", pixelBuffer);

//here is where you can split the code...

byte[] fs = File.ReadAllBytes(@"C:\..\..\test.txt");

Bitmap resultBitmap = new Bitmap(sourceBitmap.Width, sourceBitmap.Height);

BitmapData resultData = resultBitmap.LockBits(new Rectangle(0, 0,
                                    resultBitmap.Width, resultBitmap.Height),
                                    ImageLockMode.WriteOnly, PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb);

Marshal.Copy(fs, 0, resultData.Scan0, fs.Length);
            resultBitmap.UnlockBits(resultData);

pictureBox1.Image = resultBitmap;
```